# modify the Auth interface in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I know there is a interface `Guard.php` for `Auth` can do something(like `Auth::check()`),

so what i want to do is add a interface `isAdmin()` for it. how can I make it?

Comment: You can add `isAdmin()` to the ûser model and then you can do something like this `Auth::user()->isAdmin()` :) !!

Comment: @Maraboc ya maybe not like what i think but it still a good idea.thanks ^^

Comment: sure, it sounds good~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to acheave this goal :

In the User model create a function that returns if it's an admin or not :

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return true; // or false after if statement ;)
}
```

Then all you have to do is something like this :

```
Auth::user()->isAdmin();
```